# Where do I need to assign the network address and the broadcast address

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, ip-address, broadcast

I'm about to take the second CCNA module exam and I have to configure routers and switches, but I can't understand something.

So let's say i have this IP with this mask and i have to subnet, and you all know that there is an network address and a broadcast address.

Now I'm wondering what IP do I have to assign the switch and the router? And what should I do with the network and the broadcast addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network and broadcast addresses are inherent in the network as defined by the network mask. Simply assign a host address to the router interface, assign it a mask, and the router will then know what the network and broadcast addresses are. That holds true for any host on the network.

You can assign any hosts, including network devices, any of the valid host addresses. Some people assign the first host address to the router, and some people assign the last host address to the router. It doesn't matter, and it doesn't need to be any particular host address, as long as it is not assigned to any other device. It makes sense to do it the same way every time for every network you manage.

Comment: And what about the network address, should I assign it to the switch?

Comment: What ever host address you would like, assuming it is a managed switch. Unmanaged switches don't get addresses. The network devices are hosts, and they get host addresses, You decide how you want to address network hosts.